# WPF: Locate Parent Window from ListView ViewBase

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, generic.xaml

I have a ListView that allows the user to change the ViewBase through a Context Menu (it acts like a simplified version of windows explorer).

```
 <ListView Name="lv" Grid.Row ="0" Grid.Column ="1"  >
        <ListView.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="View1" Click="SwitchViewMenu"/>
                <MenuItem Header="View2" Click="SwitchViewMenu"/>                   
            </ContextMenu>
        </ListView.ContextMenu>
        <ListView.View>
            <local:View1 />
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

**The ViewBases DataTemplates are defined in a Generic.XAML file**, and i use the following Function to change the chosen view :

```
 void ChangeView(string str)
    {
        if (str == "View1")
        {
            lv.View = lv.FindResource("View1") as ViewBase;
        }
        else if (str == "View2")
        {
            lv.View = lv.FindResource("View2") as ViewBase;
        }
    }
```

**The problem:**

I got a custom CheckBox control in all the DataTemplates, that has a predefined click event attached, however when i try to move up the Parents of the CheckBox, **the highest level i can reach is the Parenting Grid in the DataTemplate in use**.

**What i need to access is the Parent Window itself.**

**Note:**
 I tried to add a Dependency Property to the Custom CheckBox Control and bind it to an extra defined variable in the sent object (The data template's items DataType object) that had a window reference as its value, but i kept getting null even though all the other dependency properties/values got bound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you're trying to get to the parents. I highly recommend [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WpfElementTrees.aspx) article (Josh Smith) to get a real understanding of what's going on in WPF.

That said, you could try `Window.GetWindow(myControl);` (static method); it should work for any pure WPF trees (for interop with WinForms, see [this](http://manfredlange.blogspot.com/2009/04/getting-parent-window-for-usercontrol.html)).

Comment: LOL! i actually found a workaround eventually that did the trick.. however your solution worked perfectly,in an easier way and with less Code. (+1) .